# Is there any tool or service for checking your server's version and detect vulnerabilities and patches?

Tags: security, monitoring, update, version-control

I am looking for a tool or something like a server/control panel that can list all the infrastructure I am using and its version (i.e. Redis Server version 6.4.x). It would be useful in order to get a better control of the infrastructure and update planning.

It is a plus if the tool can check for vulnerabilities for current services versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Request for specific product recommendations are considered off-topic.

There are numerous [vulnerability scanners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_scanner) as you can see on  lists such as this one: https://owasp.org/www-community/Vulnerability_Scanning_Tools

Be aware that just scanning version numbers can result in many false positives on Linux distributions that do security back porting, as for example explained in this Q&A [PCI Compliance: install Apache 2.4.17 on Ubuntu 14.04.3?](https://serverfault.com/q/737860/546643)

Authenticated scans can help against that by checking the version of the package, rather than the version string an application reports.

Another approach is more from the system management perspective  with centralised server management including release and patch management.
For example Ubuntu's [Landscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landscape_(software)) , Red Hat [Satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_(software)) and Microsoft [SCCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_System_Center_Configuration_Manager)